# Add overall survival curve to survival curve plot for a covariate

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I have been trying to add the 'overall' survival curve to the survival curve generated for a given covariate. the curve is generate using survival and ggsurv (GGally) in R.

I recreate the scenario using the colon dataset in survival package in R.

```
    # Load the dataset
    library (survival)
    library(GGally)
    data(colon)

    # This generates the overall survival curve (without covariates):
    kms_avg <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~1, data =colon)
    g_avg <- ggsurv(kms_avg, surv.col="red", xlab="Time (days)", lty.ci=0)
    g_avg



    # This generates the survival curve for covariate 'rx'
    table(colon$rx)
    kms_rx <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~rx, data =colon)
    g_rx <- ggsurv(kms_rx, surv.col="red", xlab="Time (days)", lty.ci=0)
    g_rx
```

Now I need to add the overall survival line to the plot g_rx. g_rx, g_avg are  ggplot2 objects.

```
# Extract the time, surv values (x,y axis values) from g_avg object  
s_avg <- summary(kms_avg) 
s_time <- s_avg$time 
s_surv <- s_avg$surv 
s <- data.frame(time=s_time, surv = s_surv)
```

Now i try to add a line to g_rx object.

```
g <- g_rx + geom_point() + geom_point(data=s, color="black")
g
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found
```

Help appreciated !

Comment: Need to assign an x and y role for the new data. Generally aes() would be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to construct all the objects you need by hand. This gives you great power. But remember, with great power comes great responsibility. Here's what I did. I merged fitted values for average model with the model where survival is modelled against `rx`. I fiddled with the colors a bit to make the average model black. Feel free to play around with colors, line types, sizes...

```
library (survival)
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
data(colon)

# This generates the overall survival curve (without covariates):
kms_avg <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~1, data =colon)
g_avg <- ggsurv(kms_avg, surv.col="red", xlab="Time (days)", lty.ci=0)

# This generates the survival curve for covariate 'rx'
kms_rx <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~rx, data =colon)
g_rx <- ggsurv(kms_rx, surv.col="red", xlab="Time (days)", lty.ci=0)

s_avg <- summary(kms_avg) 
s_rx <- summary(kms_rx)

s <- data.frame(time = s_avg$time, surv = s_avg$surv, strata = "average")
s_rx <- data.frame(time = s_rx$time, surv = s_rx$surv, strata = s_rx$strata)

xy <- rbind(s, s_rx)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = time, y = surv, color = strata)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()

ggplot(xy, aes(x = time, y = surv, color = strata)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "#e41a1c", "#377eb8", "#4daf4a"))
```

[image]

Or, you could manually define grouping.

```
g_rx + geom_point(data=s, aes(group = 1), color="black")
```

[image]